# Performance of my queries

Tags: sql-server

I am a bit puzzled by the behavior of sql server.

I have quite a big stored procedure that executes many steps. If I start it like this:

```
Exec [MyStoredProcedure] @MyBoolean=0
```

it takes longer time than calling the content of the stored procedure directly in management studio.
I have seen an answer on stackoverflow that it might come form the parameter so I added:

```
declare @IMyBoolean bit

select @IMyBoolean=@MyBoolean;
```

doing everything with @IMyBoolean afterwards, but the result was not conclusive , it was a little bit better but not that much :

> sp  : 4 minutes
>
> sp with parameter interface : 3 minutes
>
> direct sql                   2 minutes

Has anyone some explanation for this behaviour?

here is the [xmlplan](http://dl.free.fr/mJDQpxxBt)

Comment: I think you better post an image with the query plan (or the query plan XML). Right click your query window and select "Include actual execution plan". Otherwise there's no way someone can guess what's going wrong. Differences in times may be just a coincidence and caused by SQL server caching.

Comment: ok I was including time because, the direct sql was made first and lasted  2 minutes and when afterwards I tried to call the stored procedure  it took 4 minutes. I'll do as you suggest. thx

Comment: So it got better indeed. What is the duration now?

Comment: It is 1m30 now. With both the sql and the stored procedure. I suspect the calculation and caching of the query plan were the wolf I was looking for. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each query batch displayed in the plan you have a missing index with over 90% impact.

Create those indexes as suggested by the query optimizer (right click index details - green text- and select Missing Index Details).

Then post back the new results. Should be a lot faster since most of your table scans will be turned into index seeks.

The next step would be to fine tune these indexes to cover more queries, if necessary.

Comment: thanks for your help @the coon. It might optimize my queries, but does not answer the why the stored procedure is slower than the sql on its own.

Comment: The see dbaseman's answer. Try clearing the proc cache before each query and see what the difference is.